# What are the rules for playing with this unusual Mancala board?

Tags: mancala

I recently received a Mancala set hand-made from Africa.  It has an unusual set up, and I was hoping someone knew the rules for playing on this set up.

The board is an arrangement of circle and square pits in a board.  There are 4 rows and 8 columns arranged as follows (o = circle pit, x = square pit)

```
oooooooo
oooxoooo
ooooxooo
oooooooo
```

Has anyone seen a board like this before?  Does anyone know if there are rules for playing on a board like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you've got a [Bao board](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bao_%28mancala_game%29).

[image]

Bao, an East African Mancala, is the only known Mancala to make use of square pits as well as round ones. These are called *nyumba* (house), one for each player, and marks your starting position. There are also some extra rules for the *nyumba* in the main variation *Bao la kiswahili*. The Wikipedia article I've linked to has detailed instructions for both simplified (*Bao la kujifunza*) and *Bao la kiswahili*.

You can also use the same board, and ignore the shape of the special pits, to play other four-rank Mancala variants. One example would be [Omweso](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omweso). Enjoy the cool board!

Comment: That's it!  My board is just like the hinged one on the wikipedia page.  Thanks :)